# How to split a number into group word?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have written a program which will convert the numbers into words. But I found it to be a odd one, This means that instead of having individual numbers such as 42 as "forty" "two", it will be a single resource "fourty two". So the 1142 example above would be "one thousand" "," "one hundred" "and" "forty two". We will have the numbers 1-99 as separate resources, then have 100, 200, 300... and 1000, 2000, 3000... onwards. can anybody give me a help?

```
        NumberTranslator translator = new NumberTranslator();
        string translatedNumber = translator .Translate(number, languageCode);
        List<string> translatedWords = translatedNumber.Trim().Split(' ').ToList();
```

Comment: This question does not contain enough information to create a reasonable answer. Questions around this:

Comment: This question does not contain enough information to create a reasonable answer. Questions around this:
(1) Should this only work for English? If so, do you only wish to split on the word "and"?
(2) Why not adjust your NumberTranslator to emit a List<string> in the form you need it?
(3) What happens for numbers greater than 999?
(4) Are you using the American or British style? I've heard Brits say things like "forty and five" on occasion. Other variations in reading style exist even if you are only dealing with English. The "and" really is problematic.

Comment: Okay,I will edit the question

Comment: @richardtallent:- can you look on it now?, i've edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer the following link it may help you

http://forums.3drealms.com/vb/archive/index.php/t-15986.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you going to create a dictionary?

```
Dictionary<int, string> translatedNumbers = new Dictionary<int, string>();
```

Comment: Nopes i just wanna group the words like "one hundred" not like "one","hundred"